# Converting Angular's $scope to (Controller as) while using $http

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, http-get

I'm using Angular 1.3 I have changed my code to use `Controller as` from using $scope. 
I have a url:

`http://localhost:3640/api/v1/topics`

That gets the following json:

```
[
  {
    topicId: 17,
    title: "This is another BRAND SPANKIN new topic",
    body: "This is a message in the body of another topic ftw!",
    created: "2014-11-27T05:37:49.993",
    replies = null
  },

  {
    topicId: 18,
    title: "This is another BRAND new topic",
    body: "This is a message in the body of a topic wow!",
    created: "2014-11-27T05:37:49.993",
    replies = null
  }
]
```

I also have a page called index-home.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("homeIndexController", ["$http", function ($http) {

    var msg = this;
    msg.dataCount = 0;
    msg.replies = [];

    $http.get("/api/v1/topics?includeReplies=true")
        .success(function(data) {
            //Success
            msg.replies = data;
        })
        .error(function() {
            //Error
            alert('error/failed');
        });

}]);
```

On my page I use the following bindings:

```
<div id="ngController" ng-controller="homeIndexController as hic">
  ...
  <h3>Message count: {{hic.dataCount}}</h3>
  ...
  <div class="message row" data-ng-repeat="i in hic.data">
  <div class="title">{{i.title}}</div>
  <div class="date">{{i.created}}</div>
  <div class="contents">{{i.body}}</div>
</div>
```

I know that the url in the $http is working because I tried it by itself in the browser and fiddler and it returned the json. But when I use it in my angular app I get the .error result (which is a alert saying FAIL.

I have tried removing the `http://localhost:3640` and just using `/api/v1/topics` when I do that, I don't get the error result anymore. I know my controller is working and binding to the page because I get back 0 for `dataCount`.

What am I doing wrong in the `$http` method? Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: Go to the chrome's Developer Tools, Network tab & see if the request is fired from the browser. if yes, check the request details and the response stream.

Comment: @MadhavanKumar Yes the call is made and the json is returned in the response.

Comment: Thank you for the help @MadhavanKumar you got me going down a path that I quite frankly wasn't use to in my debugging. checking in F12 tools to see that data response etc. But the problem was actually very silly. I was asking for `ng-repeat="i in hic.data"` instead of `ng-repeat="i in hic.replies"` obviously a rookie mistake but hard to catch because one is pointed at the other. So  it almost made sense what I was doing without a closer look at the code. Which is usually the problem in JavaScript. We have no compiler or types to help us out there and say hey moron your calling the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your ng-repeat attribute. You do not have a data variable in your scope.
Change hic.data to hic.replies and it will work.

```
<div id="ngController" ng-controller="homeIndexController as hic">
  ...
  <h3>Message count: {{hic.dataCount}}</h3>
  ...
  <div class="message row" data-ng-repeat="i in hic.replies">
  <div class="title">{{i.title}}</div>
  <div class="date">{{i.created}}</div>
  <div class="contents">{{i.body}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm going to mark yours as correct even though I answered it myself 12 mins ago. lol

Comment: (last comment above). It's all good, I'd rather give you some points for taking the time to figure it out etc.. instead of being a jerk and marking my own answer as correct. But I promise there was no answer when I started answering it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Alright dude, this is a real rookie mistake, look at your controller:

```
app.controller("homeIndexController", ["$http", function ($http) {

    var msg = this;
    msg.dataCount = 2;
    msg.replies = [];

    $http.get("/api/v1/topics")
        .success(function(data) {
            //Success
            msg.replies = data;
        })
        .error(function() {
            //Error
            alert('eror/failed');
        });

}])
```

You are setting `this` to `msg`, then setting `msg.replies` to equal `data` if success.

This is ok.

Your problem then comes in your ng-repeat when you say:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="i in hic.data">
```

`hic.data` doesn't exist. `data` was the item returned from the `.success(function())` of the `$http.get`. You then take that `data` and assign it to `msg.replies`. So your `ng-repeat=""` should look like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="i in hic.replies">
```

Understand? This is basic stuff... I, uh I mean you should feel really silly.